# Using custom events in Javascript to trigger a function?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have this to create a Custom event in the JS code in my HTML document.

```
if (window.CustomEvent) {
  var event = new CustomEvent('not-loaded', {detail: {some: 'data'}});
} else {
  var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
  event.initCustomEvent('not-loaded', true, true, {some: 'data'});
}
this.el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

So how would I trigger a function in one of my HTML documents based on when this trigger is activated?

Comment: Just like any other event handler? `someElement.addEventListener('not-loaded', function() { ... });`

Comment: @FelixKling Which element would I use because I only have div elements in the HTML (long explanation)?

Comment: Again, just like with built-in events, you'd bind the handler to the element you want to listen on for the event, or to one of its ancestors. E.g. if I want to perform something when `<button>` is clicked, I bind the click handler to that button. If you are justing using custom events to pass messages and you actually don't need the DOM at all, something like https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS might be better suited.

Comment: Given your example in the question you'd bind it to either `this.el` or any of its ancestors.